# How to Create My Own Installation of High Performance R which Has all Packages of Revo. R and can Beat it on Performance Tests

Tags: r, revolution-r

I have Revolution-R-Community-4.3.0 which comes with R version 2.12.2. I want to update to R 2.14. I like to do this keeping some of the performance enhancing libraries of Revolution-R.

If I am to put this in another way. How is it I can create my own distribution of R which has the same performance. Also that are packaged that are included in Revo. R that I can add to my installation.

Comment: Either follow the instructions in my answer to your previous question about installing from r-forge to a not-up-to-date R, or ask Revolution R for support ...

Comment: I am voting to close. This continued effort to ignore the reality that hte Community RevoR is over a year behind the R-development status is getting tiresome.

Comment: Ought to be less than a year now as their newest is based on 2.13.2.

Comment: Are there concrete code examples in which RevoR is so much faster than normal R that you must have these improvements?

Comment: As @PaulHiemstra said: please specify some performance tests.

Comment: Some matrix algebra come to mind. But I think a lot of the high performance stuff (data.table, hadoop, mapreduce) is not specific to RevoR I think.

Comment: http://jychoi-report-cgl.blogspot.com/2009/04/compile-r-with-gotoblas.html ; http://jychoi-report-cgl.blogspot.com/2009/06/more-tips-for-using-r-with-gotoblas.html

Comment: I want to delete this question as it is not popular. How do I do it?

Comment: @SumindaSirinathSalpitikorala: please leave it so that the rest of us who are not all familiar with these issues can read this. Even a bad Q&A has tangible value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't.  REvo R's latest uses R 2.13.2.

If you want R 2.14.0, install it directly. It comes free, so there is no reason not to.

Comment: At least there is a perception that REvo is faster and more optimised.

Comment: You could (should?) compare timings from some of your own test cases between RevoR 4.3.0 and R 2.14.0 and see how much difference it makes.

Comment: You can also install your own algebra libraries to base R which will speed things up.

Comment: REvo has backing by Intel and can include the MKL, but you are free to fetch OpenBlas or GOTO Blas or Atlas ...   Linear Algebra is rarely ever the critical bottleneck.  And beyond REvo's extensions, it is the same R.  But sales people do need stories to tell...

Comment: @Suminda: RevoR can even be slower than R if you account for the extra days spent on SO and elsewhere trying to figure out why current packages won't install. Regardless, no harm in keeping a copy of current R to use when you must, along with the current RevoR to use when you prefer.